# Tabla de multiplicar da resultados inesperados

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vscode

Estoy haciendo un programa de tabla de multiplicar pero obtengo resultados inesperados. ¿A qué se debe?

```js
console.clear();
for (let n = 1; n < 11; n++) {
    console.log(`5 * ${n} = ${5 * n}`)
}
```

Y esto como pueden ver al ejecutarlo me da el resultado correcto desde el snippet, pero **en la terminal del vs code me da resultados incorrectos**

[image: salida incorrecta]

Comment: Hola @Ruslan Lopez, a mi me aparece bien del 1 al 10.

Comment: @Nor intentaste correrlo más de una vez?

Comment: Claro que si en Jsfiddle [code](https://jsfiddle.net/qLrwsyt1/1/) deberia de recibir algo distinto en VSC ?

Comment: sí, el problema como digo en la pregunta sucede únicamente en vscode

Comment: Lo acabo de probar 387423874 veces en VScode 1.53.2 y no puedo replicar tu problema. Acabo de actualizar a 1.54 y tampoco :)

Comment: ¿Haz intentado usar el while para hacer tu tabla de multiplicar?
Creo que seria mas facil si lo hacen con un while

Comment: sí, el problema no es el código